# android studio and manager error ( emulator not installed ) on M1 mac

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1

I can't run emulators on my `M1 MacBook Air`. I have downloaded an arm 64 system image on Android SDK but each time I try to create a new emulator there is an error that says `emulator not installed`. in avd setup (look at the first picture). ofcourse the emulator is created but after that in and manager there is a button that says `install emulator` which I clicked and a dialog pops up for a few seconds downloading some stuff but nothing happens. nothing is downloaded or installed

[image]

[image]

and here are the tools I have installed on sdk :

[image]

Comment: Getting the same. Any fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Android Studio `2021.1.1`.It is in canary though. [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)